# Webbrowser control on multipage control disappears when switching between the pages

Tags: excel, vba

When using a webbrowser control on a multipage control, why does switching between the pages and then back again cause the webbrowser control to disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the tab control with several webbrowser. This option has the advantage of keeping the last loaded web page of the gadget.Just create a tab control with the desired web page number. For the dimensions of webbrowser, I suggest you visually create one and take its coordinates before destroying it. Here is the code to use.

```
enter code here
Dim webbrowser(3)
Dim actuelpage

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
    webbrowser(actuelpage).Visible = False
    actuelpage = Me.TabStrip1.SelectedItem.Index
    webbrowser(actuelpage).Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim pages As Variant
    pages = Array("www.google.com", "www.allo.com", "www.microsoft.com")
    For a = 0 To UBound(webbrowser) - 1
        Set webbrowser(a) = Me.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")
        webbrowser(a).Height = 306
        webbrowser(a).Left = 30
        webbrowser(a).Top = 42
        webbrowser(a).Width = 684
        webbrowser(a).Silent = True
        webbrowser(a).navigate pages(a)
        webbrowser(a).Visible = False        
    Next a
    actuelpage = 0
    webbrowser(actuelpage).Visible = True
End Sub
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

web browser control not working on the multipage control seems a common problem, and so far I did not see a solution.

Here is the solution I devised.  It merely re-creates the web browser control each time the page is selected.

```
Dim wbr As SHDocVw.WebBrowser

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    If MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Name = "Page 1" Then

        Set wbr = Nothing
        Set wbr = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")

        wbr.Height = 700
        wbr.Left = 96
        wbr.Top = 24
        wbr.Width = 570
        wbr.Navigate "About:Blank"
        wbr.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""file:///C:\Users\User\File.pdf"" width=100% height=100%/></Body></HTML>"
        wbr.Document.body.scroll = "no"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set wbr = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")

    wbr.Height = 700
    wbr.Left = 96
    wbr.Top = 24
    wbr.Width = 570
    wbr.Navigate "About:Blank"
    wbr.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""file:///C:\Users\User\File.pdf"" width=100% height=100%/></Body></HTML>"
    wbr.Document.body.scroll = "no"
End Sub
```