# WebBrowser in userform blanks out when other objects are selected. How can I keep the site loaded?

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control

On my userform, I have WebBrowser1 on Page1 of a Multipage object. I'm using  `Sheet1.WebBrowser1.Navigate (filepath)` to display a PDF file; the filepath is listed within a TextBox on the userform, and it loads perfectly. But as soon as I select another object (CommandButton, ComboBox, etc) WebBrowser1 blanks out. The same happens if I switch to Page2 and back again; WebBrowser1 is blank. The same happens if I use a website url instead of a PDF. Is there a way to keep the file/site in WebBrowser1 loaded as I use other objects in the userform?

Comment: You should show us the code you wrote. For me, everything works fine and i can't reproduce this behavior on my computer.

Comment: The PDF filepath is stored in cell A12 of the EngineInv sheet in excel, so the code I'm using  is  literally just:
`Inv_Browse.WebBrowser1.Navigate (Sheets("EngineInv").Range("A12"))`  
The PDF displays just fine, and nothing is set to clear the filepath or overwrite this code. But when I switch pages in the Multipage object and then switch back, the PDF disappears and is replaced with the standard background color of the userform.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, disfunction of webbrower component with multipage is a known bug. Solution is to recreate the component each time the page is selected. You may read this post, it contains code doing that : [excel userform webbrowser control on multipage control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178224/excel-userform-webbrowser-control-on-multipage-control)